# OpenLDAP log monitor

Tags: linux, ldap, logging, openldap

Any good OpenLDAP log monitor which provides information user login times, host ips etc ?

Any more information about slapd access logging overlays ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [ldap-stats](http://prefetch.net/code/ldap-stats.pl.html) which gives you Webalizer-style summary of all entries.

For more detailed logging one way would be to use [slapd access logging overlay](http://linux.die.net/man/5/slapo-accesslog) and then just perform queries ("show all the logins by user X", "show all ip addresses" etc) against it with standard LDAP queries.

Comment: slapd access logging overlay appears to be what i need. Any more information about this ?

Comment: How do you configure olcAccessLog when using slap-config on for example centos 6?